# Unable to locate select the checkbox by referring to the text at the same row

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Using robot framework to automate test task and I was trying to select the checkbox by referring to one of the values/texts at the same row, for example, it will select the checkbox of level 3. Tried many ways and referred to many post but still unable to make it works, wondering what mistake have I made?

Your kind guidance is very much appreciated.

Here is my xpath:

```
xpath=//td[contains(text(),'Level 3')]/following-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']
```

also this,
`xpath=//td[contains(text(),'Level 3')]/td/input[@type='checkbox'`]

Here is my HTML

```
<table class="GridView" id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
        <tbody><tr class="GridView_HeaderStyle">
            <th scope="col" style="width:20%;" align="left"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl01_pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_1_Column" class="GridView_HeaderStyle">Level</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></th><th scope="col" style="width:60%;" align="left"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl01_pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_2_Column" class="GridView_HeaderStyle">Description</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></th><th scope="col" style="width:20%;" align="left"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl01_pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_3_Column" class="GridView_HeaderStyle">Is Sales Office</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></th><th scope="col" style="width:10%;" align="left"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl01_pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_4_Column" class="GridView_HeaderStyle">meboard</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></th>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_SelectedRowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl02_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="0" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.0'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl02$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">1</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl02_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="0" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 1</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl02_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="0" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="0" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl02_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl02$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl02$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.0'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_AlternatingRowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl03_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="1" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.1'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl03$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">2</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl03_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="1" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 2</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl03_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="1" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="1" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl03_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl03$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl03$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.1'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_RowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="2" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.2'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl04$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">3</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="2" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 3</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="2" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="2" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl04$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl04$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.2'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_AlternatingRowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl05_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="3" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.3'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl05$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">4</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl05_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="3" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 4</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl05_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="3" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="3" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl05_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl05$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl05$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.3'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_RowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl06_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="4" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.4'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl06$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">5</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl06_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="4" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 5</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl06_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="4" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="4" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl06_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl06$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl06$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.4'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_AlternatingRowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl07_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="5" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.5'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl07$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">6</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl07_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="5" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 6</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl07_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="5" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="5" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl07_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl07$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl07$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.5'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr><tr class="GridView_RowStyle">
            <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><a id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl08_LEVEL_NO_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="6" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_NO" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="GRIDROWSELECTOR" __nino.tr.tabname="-" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.LEVEL_NO.6'" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_NO" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Level.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_NO" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl08$LEVEL_NO_Value','')" tabindex="1">7</a></td><td class="Label" style="width:60%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl08_LEVEL_DESC_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="6" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="LEVEL_DESC" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.LEVEL_DESC" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Description.ITEMTEMPLATE.LEVEL_DESC">Level 7</span></td><td class="Label" style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="left"><span id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl08_SLSOFF_IND_Value" class="Label_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="6" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="SLSOFF_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="LABEL" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.SLSOFF_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.Is Sales Office.ITEMTEMPLATE.SLSOFF_IND">N</span></td><td class="CheckBox" style="width:10%;" valign="top" align="left"><span class="CheckBox_Value" __nino.tr.pagename="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New" __nino.tr.grid.rowindex="6" __nino.tr.gridname="grd_extendLevel" __nino.tr.ctrlname="meboard_IND" __nino.tr.formname="-" __nino.tr.ctrltype="CHECKBOX" __nino.tr.tabname="-" __nino.tr.sourcepagename="-" __nino.tr.grid.pageindex="0" __nino.tr.isaliaspage="False" jsid="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.ITEM.meboard_IND" __nino.builder.ctrlname="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard.ITEMTEMPLATE.meboard_IND"><input id="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl08_meboard_IND_Value" name="pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl08$meboard_IND_Value" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel$ctl08$meboard_IND_Value\',\'\')', 0)" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$get('SYS_activeElementId').value = 'pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New.grd_extendLevel.meboard_IND.6'" type="checkbox"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Do you wants to Target Level 3?

Comment: Ya, select the checkbox where the "Level 3" text appear in the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,

```
//span[@id='pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_LEVEL_DESC_Value' and contains(text(),'Level 3')]//following::input[@id='pag_AC_GT_MiniList_New_grd_extendLevel_ctl04_meboard_IND_Value']
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Ishita Shah, thanks for your help, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: I just found out i used the wrong id, once i updated it to right id as per you mentioned, it can detect the element "Level 3", but not the checkbox few columns next to it